# How do I install GoodSync?

Tags: installation, command-line

I am heavy user of GoodSync ([Link](http://www.goodsync.com/platforms/unix)) on my windows boxes, and I'd like to give the command line version a try.

So I download the Linux packet on my Ubuntu rig, and extract it, but from then on I am lost. I get the extracted files but I don't know what to do with them.

I've looked online for possible solutions like here (http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/compile-install-tar-gz-tar-bz2-files-ubuntu-linux/), but I can't wrap my brains around it. There is no install or /.config file anywhere.

What am I missing?

Comment: Manually downloading and then installing is pretty much a windows thing.  Package managers on Linux "install" for you, but that includes downloading and the whole enchilada, including putting the executables in the appropriate place for the distro.  I've never seen an "installer" on Linux that works like the ones on Windows.  Even on OS X it's the minority.  Most apps there can just be dragged to `/Applications` (or anywhere else you'd prefer to put them) and run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to compile Gsync here, since what you downloaded is the binary packages. That means there is nothing for compile. Just extract the archive and start to use it via binaries:

```
cd goodsync-release-i686 # or whatever you downloaded
./gsync
```

http://www.goodsync.com/support/manual#command_line

Comment: You can also add the location where you extracted it to the path.

Comment: Duh, I can't believe it's this simple!

Comment: Yeah, it is this simple since they are binaries :) For compiling just look for an INSTALL or README file.